# when my mac commits code using Git, rejected by Husky, prompt ` sh:command not found `

Tags: git, husky, git-husky

When my Mac commits code using Git, it gets rejected by Husky, and I see the following error:

```
> git -c user.useConfigOnly=true commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file -
.husky/_/husky.sh: line 23: sh: command not found
husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 127 (error)
```

The Terminal or VSCode also report mistakes.

How can I get past this error?

Comment: The misconfiguration of my file is causing this problem, fix this problem by modifying this file . https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/?id=command-not-found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is about [`github.com/typicode/husky/husky.sh#L23`](https://github.com/typicode/husky/blob/5d269e820e699bb0cf28e3e9a69dbe38cfda6cd5/husky.sh#L23)

```
sh -e "$0" "$@"
```

Make sure sh is in your `$PATH` (typically `/bin/sh`)

Add an `echo "prg='$0'"` to your `.husky/_/husky.sh` just to debug and check if it is '$0' which is not found (being empty)

And check, for PATH problem, the [issue 912](https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/912#issuecomment-887840695)

I use VS Code and Husky v6.

> I ran echo `$PATH` from the root of my project.
> Then I copied the output to the `pre-commit` file in the `.husky` directory.
>
> My pre-commit file looks like this:
>
> ```sh
> #!/bin/sh
> . "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"
> export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
> npx lint-staged
> ```

As mentioned by the OP, refering to [Husky/ Command not found](https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/?id=command-not-found), the `~/.huskyrc` should set NVM properly:

```sh
# ~/.huskyrc
# This loads nvm.sh and sets the correct PATH before running hook
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
```